# Python access Bevel Custom Profile handles

Tags: python, scripting

We can access the profile points via
`obj.modifiers["Bevel"].custom_profile.points[1].location`
But how to get the handles location at that point?

[image]

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: You have to interpolate `points[1]` and `points[2]` to get the handle location.

Comment: @Karan i don't think interpolation will work with the *Free Handle* type because you can't even access the values of the handles. You only have the point locations, which is not enough information for interpolation.